# My loop won't work

Tags: python

Here is my code:

```
name = raw_input("Title:")
Author = raw_input("Author:")

file = open(name+'.txt', 'a')
file.write("Title:" + name + "\n" + "Author:" + Author + "\n")
```

This part should ask for continuous contents unless you type `'x'`:

```
Contents = raw_input
while Contents != "x":
Contents = raw_input("Content:")
file.write(Contents+"\n")
if Contents != "x":
    break
file.close()
```

This part should open the text and read the file and get the total of the vowels in the contents:

```
p = 0
file = open(name+'.txt')
j = file.read()
for i in Contents:
    if i in "aeiouAEIOU":
        p += 1
print p
file.close()
```

Comment: In what way doesn't your loop work?

Comment: always start variable names with a lower case letter

Comment: It only asks for one content and I need to make ask for infinite content unless i type x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your reading of the user input to this:

```
Contents = ''
while user_input != "x":
    Contents = raw_input("Content:")
    file.write(Contents+"\n")
file.close()
```

Count the vowels in `Content`:

```
count = 0
for char Content:
    if char in "aeiouAEIOU": 
        count += 1
```

Read the file and count the vowels:

```
count = 0
with open(name+'.txt') as fobj:
    for char in fobj.read():
        if char in "aeiouAEIOU":
            count += 1
print count
```

Comment: Ups. Edited. I use `fobj` for the open file object because `file` is a built-in name that should not be used for own variables.

Comment: Hi how do you make it  just count the vowels for contents?

Comment: Just loop all characters of `Content`. Added.

Comment: You can [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) an answer if it solves your problem.

Comment: Well theres still somethin wrong with the code and I'm still trying to figure what bcos the counting is wrong

Answer (score 1):

You're breaking out of the loop if the user *doesn't* enter X.

```
if Contents != "x":
    break
```

You can just remove these two lines entirely because even if you fixed them, they would just duplicate the behavior of the `while` loop.

You also need to swap around the following two lines:

```
Contents = raw_input("Content:")
file.write(Contents+"\n")
```

You are using a classic "priming read" *before* the loop and so you should write that data before prompting for more. Otherwise you lose the first line you entered.

Comment: If I do that the vowel part doesn't work anymore and it enters x on the text file.

Comment: Added more to address that. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks it works but my problem now is that the counting of vowels doesn't anymore.